# Why is my pipe breaking (python sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from socket import *
import select

class window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, name, networker):
        self.networker = networker
        self.name=name
        self.count=0
        self.scrollx=900
        self.scrolly=0

        self.messageStr=""
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.title("Chat")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand="yes")

        self.lfone = Frame(self)

        self.messageCanvas = Canvas(self.lfone, relief=RAISED, height=0, width=0, scrollregion=(0,0,self.scrollx,self.scrolly))


        self.myentry = Entry(self)
        self.sendbutton = Button(self, text="Send", command=self.sendbuttoncommand)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.lfone)


        self.lfone.pack(fill=BOTH, expand="yes")
        self.myentry.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand="yes", padx=5)

        self.messageCanvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.sendbutton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, pady=5)


        self.messageCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.messageCanvas.yview)

        self.doListen()

    def sendbuttoncommand(self):
        self.count=self.count+20
        self.scrolly=self.scrolly+20
        str = (self.name + ": " + self.myentry.get())
        b = bytearray(str, "utf-8")
        self.messageCanvas.create_text(5, self.count, anchor=SW, text=(self.name + ": " + self.myentry.get()))
        self.messageCanvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.scrollx, self.scrolly))
        self.networker.myhost.send(b)

    def post(self, str):
        self.count=self.count + 20
        self.scrolly=self.scrolly+20
        self.messageCanvas.create_text(5, self.count, anchor=SW, text=str)
        self.messageCanvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.scrollx, self.scrolly))

    def doListen(self):
        str = self.networker.listen()
        if str != "":
            self.post(str)
        self.after(128, self.doListen)

class splash(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        parent.title("INIT")
        self.splashed=False
        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.label = Label(self, text="Choose a name")
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.doSplash())
        self.ipentry = Entry(self)
        self.iplabel = Label(self, text="IP addr to connect to:")

        self.label.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
        self.entry.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, padx=5)
        self.iplabel.pack()
        self.ipentry.pack(fill=X, padx=5)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=5)

    def doSplash(self):
        self.name=self.entry.get()
        #TODO: exception handling for ip addr
        self.addr=self.ipentry.get()
        self.splashed=True
        self.parent.destroy()

class networker():

    def __init__(self):
        self.myhost = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.myclient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host=gethostname()
        self.port=2007
        self.myhost.bind((self.host,self.port))
        self.myhost.listen(5)
        self.clientConnected=False
        self.myhost.setblocking(0)

    def connectToHost(self, hostname):
        self.myclient.connect((hostname,self.port))

    def getClient(self):
        self.client, self.addr = self.myhost.accept()
        print("Got a connection from %s" % str(self.addr))
        self.clientConnected=True

    def listen(self):
        ready = select.select([self.myclient], [], [], 1)
        if ready == 0:
            str = self.myclient.recv(1024)
            return str
        return ""



def main():

    myN = networker()

    splashRoot = Tk()
    splashApp=splash(splashRoot)
    splashRoot.mainloop()

    myN.connectToHost(splashApp.addr)
    myN.getClient()

    if splashApp.splashed:
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("900x600+300+300")
        app=window(root, splashApp.name, myN)
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So this is supposed to be a simple chat program. Sorry for all the code but I was afraid it wouldn't make sense if I cut it up.

The idea:
the networker object connects to the entered IP address (in my test cases, my own addr) and reports its success.
window takes a networker object and calls its listen() method in doListen().
doListen() uses after to multitask listening and maintaining the gui. sendbuttoncommand() is supposed to post the message in entry to both the client and the sender's screens, but is the source of the error.

Mostly it works, and claims to connect successfully. However, when I try to use window.sendbuttoncommand(), I receive a broken pipe error. I'm new to both python and network programming in general, and have no idea which of a billion things is causing this. Some of my thoughts:

1. passing the networker object into a window object might break the connection because it's not simply passing a reference like I assumed.
2. using after in window.dolisten() could be causing the server to only listen of brief periods of time and the data is not being caught in that time period.
3. connecting to my own device could be screwing something up.

any advice/help/insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is not to do what I was trying to do and use something like twisted instead. No need to reinvent the wheel